# Angularjs: push data into array from resource query and show in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

there is an array data retrieved from a `restful API` using `$resource` and i fetch it using `query()` method. so i create a new data and i want to push the data created into the fetched array from `$resource` which is shown in `ngRepeat` directive, but when i make the push function, it doesn't push and i wouldn't like to re-query the whole data again.

controller

```
self.submit = function(){ //This function is called when i submit data creation
            var form = self.form;
            form.user_id = Global.user.id;

            // hide error message if it's shown
            self.data.error.show = false;

            // check if submition is already on request (for some reason it submit twice)
            if(!self.status.request){
                self.status.request = true;

                $timeout(function(){
                    projects.save({data: form}, function(data){ //function called from $resource
                        console.log(data);
                        self.status.request = false;

                        // Resolve Error
                        if(data.error[1])
                            resolveError();

                        // merge data to list
                        else{
                            form.id = data.id;
                            mergeData(form);

                            self.closeDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000)
            }

            // show error message
            function resolveError(){
                var error = self.data.error;

                error.show = true;
            }

            // merge form data into list data
            function mergeData(data){
                self.query.push(data); //this doesn't seem to work
                console.log(data, self.query); //log to see if data is in array
            }
        }
```

view

```
<md-card ng-repeat="project in projects.query | orderBy:'id':true">
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>{{project.Name}}</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <h3>{{project.user_id}}</h3>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-card-content>
        <p>{{project.Description}}</p>
    </md-card-content>
    <div class="md-actions" layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button ng-href="#/projects/{{project.id}}">View</md-button>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

***note:*** the data is saved on the database, and for now the only way to see it on the list is by refreshing the page

***update:*** `projects` is the alias of `ProjectsController`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are describing.  your question clearly says "i fetch it using `query()` method", yet you are showing the code for a `save` operation.  also, you are calling your `mergeData` method with a `form` parameter, not the `data` parameter.

Comment: @Claies the `form` is the object created with the data choosed, and after save, server will return the id of the new record so i define it as a property on the `form` and then use the function to push it into array

Comment: so then this has nothing to do with $resource or a `query()` method at all?

Comment: Just check what `data` and `self.query` are in `mergeData`. Should be easy to find out the reason. Without this info it's hard to guess.

Comment: @dfsq `data` is an object which i am trying to push in the array, and `self.query` is an array of objects that has the same object structure like the object i am trying to push, you can check how the console logs it http://i.imgur.com/EGoblM0.png

Comment: @Claies sorry, i use `query()` to get all data from `API` and show it in `ngRepeat` directive, then i use `save()` to post data through `API`, in there i create a function to merge the data `form` into the array filled by `query()`

Comment: have you even checked to see if `form` has any values in it at this point `// merge data to list` `else{` in your code?

Comment: @Claies yes, i am logging to check if it has the values, all of them are ok

Comment: so `form` has data there, you pass it to `mergeData(form)`, and it doesn't have a value on the other side?

Comment: @Claies you can see how the log shows in the picture i sent to `dfsq`, inside this function i can see the data is merged into array, but `ngRepeat` makes no changes, i have logged the array outside the form and the array does not have the the new data i am trying to merge, the objects have the same structure but with `$$hashKey` as aditional

Comment: the data is merged into `self.query`; ok, but how does `self.query` relate to the `projects.query` that you are bound to in the HTML?

Comment: @Claies sorry for not explaining that in the question. `projects` is the alias of the controller. I will update the question to explain it

Comment: and why is that entire code block wrapped in `$timeout`?

Comment: @Claies i use `$timeout` to simulate delay transfer because this is run in the server and it responses too fast . This is for testing feedback